# unable to upload file in azure blob

Tags: python, azure, rest, file, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to upload a file into Azure blob storage. My application is hosted in the Azure app service Linux server.
Now when I request to file upload from a remote machine, I want a file to be uploaded from the given path.

I have three request parameters which take the value-form GET request

1. https://testApp.azurewebsites.net/blobs/fileUpload/
2. containerName:test
3. fileName:testFile.txt
4. filePath:C:\Users\testUser\Documents

   ```
   @app.route("/blobs/fileUpload/")
   def fileUpload():

      container_name = request.form.get("containerName")
      print(container_name)
      local_file_name =request.form.get("fileName")
      print(local_file_name)
      local_path =request.form.get('filePath')
      ntpath.normpath(local_path)
      print(local_path)
      full_path_to_file=ntpath.join(local_path,local_file_name)
      print(full_path_to_file)
      # Upload the created file, use local_file_name for the blob name
      block_blob_service.create_blob_from_path(container_name, 
      local_file_name, full_path_to_file)
      return jsonify({'status': 'fileUploaded'})
   ```

*local_path =request.form.get('filePath')* the value which I get from the request is **C:\Users\testUser\Documents\**
becasue of which I get this error

> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\Users\testUser\Documents\testFile.txt'

all I want is to get the same path that I send in the request. Since the application is hosted in the Linux machine it treats the path as a UNIX file system if I use OS.path

please help me with this

Comment: Do you have more issues about this?

Comment: Thanks @Ivan, I get it, the file should be locally present to use create_blob_from_path. But what should be the approach if there is a client-server scenario say I want to request a file upload from the client-side?

Comment: Since you're using web app, here is an [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54729137/django-azure-upload-file-to-blob-storage) which use django framework to upload local file to blob storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the error message says, the local path is invalid for  'C:\Users\testUser\Documents\testFile.txt'. It means that there is no such file path in your local system.

If you want to use `create_blob_from_path` method, you should download the file to your local system first, then use the method to upload to blob storage.

Or you can get the stream / text of the file from remote, then use `create_blob_from_stream` / `create_blob_from_text` method respectively.